# Weird error when user does not provide picture name in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm having this weird error, I want my bot to say "Please provide a picture name" when the user doesn't enter the name but instead it shows a random picture.

**Code:**

```js
const scraper = require("images-scraper");

const google = new scraper({
    puppeteer: {
        headless: true,
    }
});

const Command = require("../Structers/Command.js");

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "pic",
    description: "Show picture.",
    async run(message, args, client){
        let image_query = args.join(" ");
        if(!image_query) return message.channel.send("Please provide a picture name");

        const image_results = await google.scrape(image_query, 1);
        return message.channel.send(`${image_results[0].url}`);
    }
});
```

Any solutions?

Comment: `image_query` seems to have a content, log it and you'll see

Comment: What is `args`?

Comment: Please provide more context and information such as the encountered error, what its supposed to do, and log `args`